# GLX_EXT_context_priority not supported on SteamOS?

Tags: ubuntu, amd, steam, glx

I want to set `GLX_CONTEXT_PRIORITY_LEVEL_EXT` when create context `glXCreateContextAttribsARB`. But it seems that the extension `GLX_EXT_context_priority` is not supported now. Is there any method to solve this problem.

My SteamOS version is 3.4.11
Graphics Processor: AMD Custom GPU 0405

I use `glxinfo | grep GLX_EXT_context_priority` and get nothing returned.